# Rails Render part of a form inside another form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a page in which you create an invoice. There is a separate section that allows you to add payments to invoices. What I'm wanting to do is add the ability to create a payment when creating an invoice.

I'm wanting to render the "Create Payment" form VIEW into the "Create Invoice" form VIEW. How can I do this? Here is some code:

Invoice Form view (notice the render call):

```
<%= form_for(@contract) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    f.label "Add payment?"
    <div id="pay_form">
      <%= render 'payments/pay_form' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

(_pay_form.html.erb) The partial from the create payment form (notice I'm not including the form_for tag here because I don't want to next a form inside of another form on the Invoice page above):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Amount Paid:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Payment Method' %>
  <%= f.select :method, %w(Cash Credit Check) %>
</div>
```

The main problem is the `f` variable in the partial doesn't exist. And even if I assign the Invoice's `f` var from it's form, the names of the params would be `params[:invoice][:amount]` rather than `params[:payment][:amount]`. See what I'm saying?

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Did you check [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [fields_for helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the `f` variable from the view to the partial.

To do this, change

```
<%= render 'payments/pay_form' %>
```

into

```
<%= render 'payments/pay_form', f: f %>
```

Should you encounter name errors, since both are named `f`

try:

```
<%= render :partial => 'payments/pay_form', :locals => { :f => f} %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for(@contract) do |builder| %>
  <div class="field">
    builder.label "Add payment?"
    <div id="pay_form">
      <%= render 'payments/pay_form', f: builder %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

For further learning, I think what you are really looking for is nested forms.

Here are some good tutorials on this subject, if you are interesting in learning about them:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Thanks for this response. Because of how I have it, the payments aren't directly associated with the contracts, so originally I ignored the idea for accepts_nested_attributes_for. However, I completely forgot about the fields_for helper, which is exactly what I was needing to be able to use the partial (which used formbuilder vars `f`) without creating another form inside the original form. You led me down the right path!